# C subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector when assigning an array element value

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry for asking the already answered question, I am a newbie to C and don't understand the solutions.
Here is my function

```
int rotateArr(int *arr) {
    int D[4][4];
    int i = 0, n =0;
    for(i; i < M; i ++ ){
        for(n; n < N; n++){
            D[i][n] = arr[n][M - i + 1];
        }
    }
    return D;
}
```

It throws an error

> main.c|23|error: subscripted value is neither array nor
>   pointer nor vector|

on line

> D[i][n] = arr[n][M - i + 1];

What's wrong? I am just setting the value of an array element to another array element.

The arr passed is declared as

```
int S[4][4] = { { 1, 4, 10, 3 }, { 0, 6, 3, 8 }, { 7, 10 ,8, 5 },  { 9, 5, 11, 2}  };
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `int rotateArr(int **arr)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C lets you use the subscript operator `[]` on arrays and on pointers. When you use this operator on a pointer, the resultant type is the type to which the pointer points to. For example, if you apply `[]` to `int*`, the result would be an `int`.

That is precisely what's going on: you are passing `int*`, which corresponds to a vector of integers. Using subscript on it once makes it `int`, so you cannot apply the second subscript to it.

It appears from your code that `arr` should be a 2-D array. If it is implemented as a "jagged" array (i.e. an array of pointers) then the parameter type should be `int **`.

Moreover, it appears that you are trying to return a local array. In order to do that legally, you need to allocate the array dynamically, and return a pointer. However, a better approach would be declaring a special `struct` for your 4x4 matrix, and using it to wrap your fixed-size array, like this:

```
// This type wraps your 4x4 matrix
typedef struct {
    int arr[4][4];
} FourByFour;
// Now rotate(m) can use FourByFour as a type
FourByFour rotate(FourByFour m) {
    FourByFour D;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++ ){
        for(int n = 0; n < 4; n++){
            D.arr[i][n] = m.arr[n][3 - i];
        }
    }
    return D;
}
// Here is a demo of your rotate(m) in action:
int main(void) {
    FourByFour S = {.arr = {
        { 1, 4, 10, 3 },
        { 0, 6, 3, 8 },
        { 7, 10 ,8, 5 },
        { 9, 5, 11, 2}
    } };
    FourByFour r = rotate(S);
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i ++ ){
        for(int n=0; n < 4; n++){
            printf("%d ", r.arr[i][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This [prints the following](http://ideone.com/7vjlU8):

```
3 8 5 2 
10 3 8 11 
4 6 10 5 
1 0 7 9
```

Answer (score 11):

You are not passing your 2D array correctly. This should work for you

```
int rotateArr(int *arr[])
```

or

```
int rotateArr(int **arr)
```

or

```
int rotateArr(int arr[][N])
```

Rather than returning the array pass the target array as argument. See John Bode's answer.

Comment: `int **` and `int [][N]` are not equivalent.

Comment: Even with a cast `(int **)S`, `int **` is not able to represent `int[4][4]`, and `(int *arr[])` must be `(int (*arr)[4])`

Comment: Acme, see the answer of John Bode

Answer (score 6):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

If the declaration of the array being passed is

```
int S[4][4] = {...};
```

then when you write

```
rotateArr( S );
```

the expression `S` has type "4-element array of 4-element array of `int`"; since `S` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to 4-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[4]`, and this *pointer* value is what actually gets passed to `rotateArr`.  So your function prototype needs to be one of the following:

```
T rotateArr( int (*arr)[4] )
```

or

```
T rotateArr( int arr[][4] )
```

or even

```
T rotateArr( int arr[4][4] )
```

In the context of a function parameter list, declarations of the form `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.

You're probably wondering why I changed the return type from `int` to `T`.  As written, you're trying to return a value of type "4-element array of 4-element array of `int`"; unfortunately, you can't do that.  C functions *cannot* return array types, nor can you assign array types.  IOW, you can't write something like:

```
int a[N], b[N];
...
b = a; // not allowed
a = f(); // not allowed either
```

Functions can return *pointers* to arrays, but that's not what you want here.  `D` will cease to exist once the function returns, so any pointer you return will be invalid.

If you want to assign the results of the rotated array to a different array, then you'll have to pass the target array as a parameter to the function:

```
void rotateArr( int (*dst)[4], int (*src)[4] )
{
  ...
  dst[i][n] = src[n][M - i + 1];
  ...
}
```

And call it as

```
int S[4][4] = {...};
int D[4][4];

rotateArr( D, S );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `arr` is not (declared as) a 2D array, and you are treating it as if it were 2D.

Answer (score 0):

You have "int* arr" so "arr[n]" is an int, right? Then your "[M - 1 + 1]" bit is trying to use that int as an array/pointer/vector.

Answer (score 0):

the second subscript operator is invalid here.
You passed a int * pointer into function,  which is a 1-d array. So only one subscript operator can be used on it.

Solution : you can pass int ** pointer into funciton