# Loop To Find Last Even Number In An Array in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to find the index of the last element containing an even number in an array, A, with 'length' number of elements.
For example, for `A = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7}` we would return 2 as the value 4 is the last even number and it is at index 2 in the array.
I am required to use a for loop where the fewest number of elements need to be tested, where the first line follows the format:
`for ( i = ??; i > ??; i =  ??)`

I think there's something wrong with the first line of my code but I don't know how to fix it.

```
for ( i = length-1; i >= 0; i =  i-1) { 
if ( A[i] % 2 == 0) { // value mod 2 = 0 indicates even
    return i;
}
```

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
     'if (A[i]% 2==0) { // value mod 2 = 0 indicates even'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, and also copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output to show us.

Comment: *"subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"* Well, what is `A`, then? Please post your whole code, not just a snippet.

Comment: The compiler tells you that your "array A" is not an array.

Comment: Aside:: if your loop supposed to  follow this format `for ( i = ??; i > ??; i =  ??)` then `for ( i = length-1; i >= 0; i =  i-1)` should be `for ( i = length-1; i > -1; i =  i-1)`

Comment: That's a weird question: "I am required to use a for loop where the fewest number of elements need to be tested": either you use a for-loop and test all entries, or you use a while-loop and have the fewest number of elements tested. Or is it the intention to make you write a while-loop using a for-clause?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write it:

```
int num = -1;
for ( i = length-1; i > -1; i = i-1) {
  //Check if the array is even
  if( A[i] % 2 == 0 )

    // If it hasn't found an even number yet, automatically set num equal to the index
    // This avoids accessing the element in the "-1" position in the array which would
    //    give an error
    if( num == -1 )
      num = i;

    // If the element at the 'i' position is greater than the previous greatest element
    //   then set num equal to the index
    else if( A[i] > A[num] )
      num = i;
}

// It will return -1 if an even number isn't found
return num;
```

This will work if A is an array. It sounds like A currently isn't the array you're thinking it is; it may be an array of arrays or something similar. If you post the rest of your code it will help to resolve the error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908456/c-subscripted-value-is-neither-array-nor-pointer-nor-vector-when-assigning-an-ar) may help you with your error